# Interfacing a 4x4 keypad matrix with Atmega32

Tags: c, atmega, keypad

I am trying to interface an Atmega32 micro-controller with a 16x2 LCD and a 4x4  keypad matrix. I am simulating with Proteus and using WinAVR compiler.

The LCD part is okay (I have thoroughly tested it). The keypad code, however, is not running as I expect. **Whenever I press a key, the scanning of keypad rows stops indefinitely**.

Also the key doesn't display on the LCD. Please help me find the bug.

Below is the circuit schematic as drawn in Proteus, as well as the code. I have not included code for the LCD here since I know that part is working perfectly well.

**Circuit:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>



//Keypad Information
#define R0 0
#define R1 1
#define R2 2
#define R3 3
#define C0 4
#define C1 5
#define C2 6
#define C3 7

#define keypadPORT PORTA
#define keypadPIN PINA
#define keypadDDR DDRA


//Keypad functions and global variables
char getkey();
int keypadRow[] = {R0, R1, R2, R3}; //rows of the keypad
int keypadCol[] = {C0, C1, C2, C3};//columnd



int main()
{
   char key_pressed;

   keypadDDR |= (1<<R0)|(1<<R1)|(1<<R2)|(1<<R3);//set upper part of keypad port as output
                                                //this will be required for scanning the rows
   keypadDDR &= ~((1<<C0)|(1<<C1)|(1<<C2)|(1<<C3));//set lower part of keypad port as input.This is
                                                   //the part of the keypad port where the rows are connected.

   LCD_init(); //initialize LCD

   while(1)
   {
      key_pressed = getkey();
      switch(key_pressed)
      {
        case('A'):
            break;//do nothing if no key is pressed
        default:
            send_char(key_pressed);//send the key pressed to LCD
      }
   }     
   return 0;
}



char getkey()
{  
   int i, j;
   for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
    keypadPORT = 0x00;
    keypadPORT |= (1 << keypadRow[i]);//send a high to a particular row of the keypad

    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if(bit_is_set(keypadPIN,keypadCol[j]))//check if key is pressed
        {
            while(bit_is_set(keypadPIN,keypadCol[j]));  //wait for key to be released
            switch(i)
            {
                case(0):
                {
                    if (j == 0) return '7';
                    else if (j == 1) return '8';
                    else if (j == 2) return '9';
                    else if (j == 3) return '/';
                    break;
                }
                case(1):
                {
                    if (j == 0) return '4';
                    else if (j == 1) return '5';
                    else if (j == 2) return '6';
                    else if (j == 3) return '*';
                       break;
                }
                case(2):
                {
                    if (j == 0) return '1';
                    else if (j == 1) return '2';
                    else if (j == 2) return '3';
                    else if (j == 3) return '-';
                       break;
                }
                case(3):
                {
                    if (j == 0) return '?';
                    else if (j == 1) return '0';
                    else if (j == 2) return '=';
                    else if (j == 3) return '+';
                       break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
   }
    return 'A';//Return 'A' if no key is pressed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If, whenever you press a key, "the scanning of keypad rows stops indefinitely" and "the key doesn't display on the LCD", then I'd be looking at any potential infinite loops, such as the following line:

```
while(bit_is_set(keypadPIN,keypadCol[j]));
```

I don't know whether the columns drain away to ground or stay high when you release the key but you should be able to check that behaviour by replacing that line with:

```
send_char('<');
while(bit_is_set(keypadPIN,keypadCol[j]));
send_char('>');
```

If you are indeed getting caught in an infinite loop there, the display should show you the `<`.